# What level does the winner start on?

Tags: arcade, street-fighter-series

**In the arcade version of Street Fighter II, when a challenger beats the current player who has a game in progress, what level does the challenger start off at?** Does the challenger restart or continue on the last player's level?

Was there a difference with Mortal Combat?

Comment: How does the preamble relate to the actual question?

Comment: Good point, I removed the intro.

Answer (score 2):

I've got no way to test right now, but if I recall correctly, the challenger continues the game on the last player's level. Also, if there was a fight with the character that lost the match, this fight would be skipped.